# Any good .net membership user / group management controls?

Tags: .net, controls, membership

I am looking for any decent .Net membership components which can take the membership provider settings from the web.config and display the users / groups on an ASP .Net web page.

I have a client requirement to be able to update / create / delete users as well as add / remove them from groups. There must be a decent control set out there for doing this from the front end without having to write a set of custom controls to iterate over the membership API from scratch.

Also, the membership providers are custom providers from the CMS system using their own tables so the system would have to be able to interact directly via the currently configured providers.

Comment: Can't you do that directly in IIS7 management console?

Comment: Got to be IIS6 as this is an internally hosted government website and there's no room for negotiation in this scenario.